# Am I Deleting my struct Properly?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

This is a homework assignment. The Field container was the assignment from a week ago, and now I'm supposed to use the Field container to act as a dynamic array for a  struct NumPair which holds two `char *` like so:

```
struct NumPair
{
 char *pFirst, *pSecond;
 int count;

 NumPair( char *pfirst = "", char *psecond = "", int count = 0)
  : pFirst(strdup(pfirst)), pSecond(strdup(psecond)), count(count)
 { }

NumPair( const NumPair& np )
    : count(np.count), pFirst(strdup(np.pFirst)), pSecond(strdup(np.pSecond))
{   }

NumPair& operator=( const NumPair& np )
{
    if(this != &np)
    {
        pFirst  = strdup(np.pFirst);
        pSecond = strdup(np.pSecond);
        count = np.count;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

and the Field container

```
Field<NumPair> dict_;
```

The homework requires the use of `char *`, and not string, so that we can get better with all this low-level stuff. I've already had some question about char to wchar_t conversions, etc.

Now I have a question as to whether or not I'm destructing the NumPair properly. The scenario is as follows:

1) Field destructor gets called

```
template <class T>
Field<T>::~Field()
{
 delete[] v_;
}
```

2) Delete calls the destructor of every element NumPair in v_;

```
~NumPair()
{
 free(pFirst);
 free(pSecond);
}
```

Is this okay? I haven't really read too many articles about mixing and matching elements created on the heap and free-store as we wish. I figure as long as I don't use delete on an improper malloc'ed element, I should be fine.

However, I don't know the entire intricacies of the delete command, so I'm wondering whether or not this is valid design, and what I could do to make it better.

Also, of course this isn't. I'm getting an error of the type:

`This may be due to a corruption of the heap` and points to `dbgheap`

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
  const void * pUserData
  )
{
  if (!pUserData)
   return FALSE;

  if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
   return FALSE;

  return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) ); // Here
}
```

Again, how could I improve this without the use of string?

**FIELD CTOR/Copy Ctor/Assignment**

```
template <class T>
Field<T>::Field()
    : v_(0), vused_(0), vsize_(0)
{ }

template <class T>
Field<T>::Field(size_t n, const T &val)
    : v_(0), vused_(n), vsize_(0)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        vsize_ = 1;
        while(vsize_ < n)
            vsize_ <<= 1;

        v_     = new T[vsize_];
        std::fill(v_, (v_ + vused_), val);
    }
}

template <class T>
Field<T>::Field(const Field<T> &other)
    : v_(new T[other.vsize_]), vsize_(other.vsize_), vused_(other.vused_)
{ 
    std::copy(other.v_, (other.v_ + other.vused_), v_);
}

template <class T>
Field<T>& Field<T>::operator =(const Field<T> &other)
{
    this->v_     = other.v_;
    this->vused_ = other.vused_;
    this->vsize_ = other.vsize_;

    return *this;
}
```

**FIELD MEMBERS**

```
T *v_;
size_t vsize_;
size_t vused_;
```

Comment: Please show Field's constructor.

Comment: Do note, that unless you define your copy constructors, several `NumPair` may reference the same `char*`, and the first one to go out of scope will `free` them. After that, the first access is of course UB, but a second `free` may lead to even nastier surprises.

Comment: When you run into a heap problem, quite often the bug is somewhere quite a bit earlier than where the program warned or crashed.

Comment: I have updated the question with a Field ctor and the NumPair Copy Ctor and Assignment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor (of Field<>) seems OK, but the `operator=` is problematic.

Not only does it leak memory (what happens to the original `v_`?), but after that, two instances of Field<> hold a pointer to the same block of memory, and the one that is destructed first will invalidate the others `v_` - and you can't even tell whether that has happened.

It's not always easy to decide how to deal with `operator=` - some think that implicit move semantics are okay, but the rest of us see how that played out with the majority of people, with `std::auto_ptr`. Probably the easiest solution is to disable copying altogether, and use explicit functions for moving ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Your string handling in NumPair looks ok (strdup + free) and your Field container delete[] looks okay but it's hard to say because you don't show what v_ is.

eq mentions in a comment that you should also beware of how you are copying NumPairs.  By default, C++ will give you an implicit member-wise copy constructor.  This is where a RAII type like std::string makes your life easier:  Your std::string containing struct can be copied without any special handling on your part and memory referenced in the string will be taken care of by the *string's* copy.  If you duplicate your NumPair (by assigning it or returning it from a function for example) then the destruction of the temporary will free your strings out from under you.

Comment: @Femaref, no, it wouldn't compile if that was the case. You can't use delete on an array of non-pointer elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor for Field just copies the pointers in v_. If you have two copies of a Field, all of the NumPairs in v_ will be deleted when the first Field goes out of scope, and then deleted again when the second one does.